# Return True/False After Accessing Database Stored Procedure with VB.Net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am writing a program in VB.Net to interface with an SQL Server database I have been creating.  Within the database I have created the following Stored Procedure in order to add new entries to one of the tables in the database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreatePurchaseOrder(
    @OrderNum VARCHAR(20),
    @JobNum   VARCHAR(10),
    @Supplier VARCHAR(75),
    @Contact  VARCHAR(100),
    @User     VARCHAR(100),
    @Notes    VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @JobID int, @SupplierID int, @ContactID int, @UserID int, @StatusID int

    SELECT @JobID = job_id
      FROM jobs
     WHERE job_number = @JobNum

    SELECT @SupplierID = supplier_id
      FROM suppliers
     WHERE supplier_name = @Supplier

    SELECT @ContactID = contact_id
      FROM supplier_contacts
     WHERE (first_name = SUBSTRING(@Contact, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @Contact) - 1) AND
            last_name = SUBSTRING(@Contact, CHARINDEX(' ', @Contact) + 1, LEN(@Contact))) OR
           (first_name = SUBSTRING(@Contact, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @Contact) - 1)) AND 
           supplier_id = @SupplierID

    SELECT @UserID = users_id
      FROM users
     WHERE first_name = SUBSTRING(@User, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @User) - 1) AND
           last_name = SUBSTRING(@User, CHARINDEX(' ', @User), LEN(@User))

    SELECT @StatusID = status_id
      FROM purchase_statuses
     WHERE status_description = 'Ordered'

    IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT order_id FROM purchase_orders WHERE order_number = @OrderNum))
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO purchase_orders(order_number, job_id, supplier_id, contact_id, users_id, status_id, notes)
            VALUES (@OrderNum, @JobID, @SupplierID, @ContactID, @UserID, @StatusID, @Notes)
            RETURN 0
        END
    ELSE
        RETURN 1
END
```

The purpose of the procedure is to create a new file in the database, and if the file insertion is successful, return a 0.  If it is a failure, return 1.  I am trying to keep the boolean return values consistent with SQL, since on normal successful queries SQL returns 0 for success, and 1 for error/failure iirc.

Anyway, I am having an issue of getting my boolean return value when I access the stored procedure with my VB.Net program.  This is the method which calls the procedure (it is a generic method made for calling any `SqlCommand`)

```
Public Function ExecuteCMD(ByRef CMD As SqlCommand) As DataSet
    Dim DS As New DataSet()
    Try
        OpenDBConnection()
        CMD.Connection = DB_CONNECTION
        If CMD.CommandText.Contains(" ") Then
            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Else
            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        EndIf
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 300
        adapter.Fill(DS)
        CloseDBConnection()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Database Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return DS
End Function
```

When I call my `ExecuteCMD()` Function for my `CreatePurchaseOrder` procedure, the dataset it is returning has no values in it at all.  As such I cannot detect whether the table insertion was successful or not.  Do I need to change something on the SQL end in order to get my desired result?  Or is it something in the .Net code that I need to change?

EDIT:  This is the code where the `ExecuteCMD()` Function is called:

```
Public Function CreatePurchaseOrder(ByVal orderNum As String, ByVal jobNum As String, ByVal supplier As String, ByVal contact As String, ByVal user As String, Optional ByVal notes As String = "") As Boolean
    Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("CreatePurchaseOrder")
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@OrderNum", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = orderNum ' L154-2002'
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@JobNum", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = jobNum 'L154'
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@Supplier", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = supplier 'A2A Systems'
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@Contact", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contact 'Ian '
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user 'John Doe'
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@Notes", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = notes
    CreatePurchaseOrder = CBool(ExecuteCMD(CMD).ToString())
End Function
```

End comments at the end of each parameter addition are examples of a data set that would be used.

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the parameters required by the stored procedure?

Comment: Sounds like you could use an OUTPUT parameter in your procedure. [Here's how you can return information from a proc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Steve That has been editted and added to the OP

Comment: the DataAdapter is designed to capture the results of a SELECT statement, not a RETURN statement. So you could just to `SELECT 1` at the end. And you could use ExecuteScalar() instead to get a single value, instead of using a whole dataset to contain 1 field. Some options are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017 . As you can see `RETURN 1` is usually used to signify something specific, rather than just a validation error.

Comment: One thing I noticed separate from the question is the `ExecuteCMD()` function forces you to write horribly insecure SQL. The only way to supply parameter data to that function is to embed it in the sql CMD string, and that will leave horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks... it's practically _begging_ to get hacked.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn surely it's possible that the SqlCommand object passed in might already have had some bound parameters added to it?

Comment: @ADyson you are correct. I somehow skimmed past  "Sqlcommand" and just read "string". :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a stored procedure ends with a RETURN x you could retrieve the value of x using a parameter with the property Direction set to ParameterDirection.ReturnValue.
And you don't need the DataSet and the DataAdapter to get this value

You could change your method in this way (Note that I assume you have already prepared the 6 parameters required by your SP

```vb
Public Function ExecuteCMDWithReturnValue(ByRef CMD As SqlCommand) As Boolean
    Try
        OpenDBConnection()
        CMD.Connection = DB_CONNECTION
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@ret", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
        ' Well, this should be done when you create and prepare the command, not here.
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim result As Object = CMD.Parameters("@ret").Value
        Return If(Convert.ToInt32(result) = 1, False, True) 
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Database Error:  " & ex.Message)
        Return False    
    Finally
        CloseDBConnection()
    End Try
End Function
```

Notice that trying to create a do-it-all common method for every possible case of database interaction is a task very complex. I suggest you to use a proper ORM to handle your database tasks or, at least, write a database layer that is specific for each of your tasks and not generic to serve everything.